# How to redirect WORDPRESS hotlinked image ( for exp : Image.jpg) to post/page where it is?

Tags: image, wordpress, redirect

Recently google change image search and as a result most of the traffic click over view original image and it send them to direct image file.

I have changed my .htaccess and stop all hot linking and redirect to my homepage if they click over image file.

Recently I've also tried if it is possible to redirect to post or page where image is.

By the following code

```
<?php 
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
$imageURL = strip_tags( $_GET['id'] );
if imageURL!== "") {    
  $query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'AND post_parent > '0' AND guid = '$imageURL'";    
  $linkedImage = $wpdb-get_row($query);    
  $attachmentUrl = get_attachment_link($linkedImage->ID);    
  if($attachmentUrl !== "" && !is_numeric(stripos($attachmentUrl, "attachment_id=0"))) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");        
    header("Location: ". $attachmentUrl);        
    exit;    
  }
}
$newUrl = get_site_url() . "/image-not-found";
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Location: " . $newUrl);
exit;
?>
```

But it redirect to http://www.mydomain.com/?attachment_id=

id is nil  or can't fetch the proper id

My website in Wordpress CMS version 3.5.1

can anyone help  how to redirect to proper attachment page for .jpg file direct request.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your code would only work if there was an ID parameter on the requested URL that would be an exact match with the image URL, for instance http://www.example.com/?id=http://www.example.com/uploads/Some-Image.jpg

Is this the case? Even so, you shouldn't use `id` since it's a reserved parameter for other things in WP. In your .htaccess, you should redirect http://www.example.com/uploads/Some-Image.jpg to, for example, http://www.example.com/?image_redirect=http://www.example.com/uploads/Some-Image.jpg. Then use `$imageURL = $_GET['image_redirect']`.

Other notes: `strip_tags` doesn't make a string safe to use as a SQL query. In WordPress, you have `esc_sql($string)` for that. Also, you should rather use `if ( $imageUrl != '' )`, not with `!==`. And there's an error on line 5, it should say `$wpdb->get_row`, you currently have a minus sign. I assume these are typos. And finally, you shouldn't use `Location:` header with a status code 404.